# List Adding to view model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

If x.ChildPeople is null then I will get an error `Value cannot be null.` I have been trying to use `x.ChildPeople.any()`. Is there a different way to do this?

```
var listOfPeople= es.GetPeople().Select(x => new PeopleViewModel
                  {
                     PeopleId = x.PeopleId,
                     Name = x.Name,
                     Child = x.ChildPeople.Select(c => new PeopleViewModel
                             {
                                PeopleId = c.PeopleId,
                                Name = c.Name
                             }).ToList()
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `null` operator with x.ChildPeople

```
Child = x.ChildPeople?.Select(c => new PeopleViewModel
         {
            PeopleId = c.PeopleId,
            Name = c.Name
         }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good situation to use a ?. operator:

```
 Child = x.ChildPeople?.Select(c => new PeopleViewModel
 {
   PeopleId = c.PeopleId,
   Name = c.Name
 }).ToList()
```

Note that Child will be null if c is for a specific element.

It might be better to just sneak in an if statement and check for c being null and then do some sort of custom logic:

```
 if (x.ChildPeople == null)
 {
   Child = new PeopleViewModel();
 }
 else
 {
   Child = x.ChildPeople.Select(c => new PeopleViewModel
   {
      PeopleId = c.PeopleId,
        Name = c.Name
      }).ToList()
   }
 }
```

Comment: can I add the if statement into the collection `var listOfPeople`

Comment: It would go inside the delegate inside the Select()